# Expand the function $f(z)=\frac{1}{(z-a)(z-b)}$ where $0 < |a| < |b|$ in a Laurent series in different annuli

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, laurent-series

I have to expand the function $f(z) = \frac{1}{(z-a)(z-b)}$ where $a, b \in \mathbb{C}$, $0 < |a| < |b|$ in the following annuli:

(a) $0<|z|<|a|$

(b) $|a|<|z|<|b|$

(c) $|b|<|z|$

I made bonafide attempts at $(b)$ and $(c)$, which I'll share below; however, I was not sure what to do about the $0<|z|$ part in (a). I'm kind of teaching these to myself, and the only examples I've seen with a $0$ in them have involved something like $0< |z+2| <|a|$, or something like that where you'd have to make a substitution $w$... **Please let me know how to take care of examples like (a).**

**Also, here are my attempts at parts (b) and (c). Please let me know if they're correct, and if not, let me know what I need to do in order to fix them:**

> (b) $\mathbf{|a|<|z|<|b|}$. Using partial fractions, I wrote $\frac{1}{(z-a)(z-b)} = \frac{1}{a-b}\left( \frac{1}{z-a}\right) - \frac{1}{a-b}\left( \frac{1}{z-b}\right)$.
>
> Now, if $|z|> |a|$, then $\left\vert \frac{a}{z}\right\vert< 1$, so we write $\frac{1}{(a-b)(z-a)} = \frac{1}{(a-b)z(1-a/z)} = \frac{1}{a-b}\cdot \frac{1}{z} \cdot \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left( \frac{a}{z}\right)^{n} = \frac{1}{(a-b)}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{a^{n}}{z^{n+1}}$.
>
> If $|z|<|b|$, then $\left\vert \frac{z}{b}\right\vert < 1$, so we write $\displaystyle \frac{-1}{(a-b)}\cdot \frac{1}{(z-b)} = \frac{-1}{(a-b)}\cdot \frac{1}{b\left( \frac{z}{b} - 1 \right)} = \frac{1}{b(a-b)}\frac{1}{1-\frac{z}{b}} = \frac{1}{b(a-b)}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left( \frac{z}{b}\right)^{n} = \frac{1}{(a-b)}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{z^{n}}{b^{n+1}}$
>
> So, the whole expansion is $\displaystyle \frac{1}{z-b} \left( \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{a^{n}}{z^{n+1}} + \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{z^{n}}{b^{n+1}}\right)\\ \displaystyle  = \frac{1}{a-b} \left( \frac{1}{z} + \frac{a}{z^{2}} + \frac{a^{2}}{z^{3}} + \cdots + \frac{1}{b} + \frac{z}{b^{2}}+\frac{z^{2}}{b^{3}}+\cdots\right) \\ \displaystyle =  \frac{1}{z(a-b)} + \frac{a}{z^{2}(a-b)} + \frac{a^{2}}{z^{3}(a-b)} + \cdots + \frac{1}{b(a-b)} + \frac{z}{b^{2}(a-b)}+\frac{z^{2}}{b^{3}(a-b)}+\cdots$
>
> (c) $\mathbf{|b|<|z|}$.  If $|a|<|z|$, we have, as in part (b) $\displaystyle \frac{1}{(a-b)}\frac{1}{(z-a)} = \frac{1}{(a-b)}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{a^{n}}{z^{n+1}}$.
>
> If $|b|<|z|$, $\displaystyle \frac{1}{(a-b)}\frac{1}{(z-b)} = \frac{1}{(a-b)} \frac{1}{z \left( 1 - \frac{b}{z}\right)}   \\ \displaystyle = \frac{1}{(a-b)}\frac{1}{z} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left( \frac{b}{z}\right)^{n} \\ \displaystyle = \frac{1}{(a-b)}\frac{1}{z}\left( 1 + \frac{b}{z} + \frac{b^{2}}{z^{2}} + \cdots \right) \\ \displaystyle = \frac{1}{(a-b)} \left( \frac{1}{z} + \frac{b}{z^{2}} + \frac{b^{2}}{z^{3}}+ \cdots\right)$
>
> Then, the required Laurent expansion valid for both $|z|>|a|$ and $|z|>|b|$ is found by subtraction:
>
> $ \displaystyle  \frac{1}{(a-b)} \left( \frac{1}{z} - \frac{1}{z} + \frac{a}{z^{2}} - \frac{b}{z^{2}} + \frac{a^{2}}{z^{3}} - \frac{b^{2}}{z^{3}} + \cdots \right) \\ \displaystyle = \frac{1}{(a-b)} \left( \frac{a-b}{z^{2}} + \frac{a^{2}-b^{2}}{z^{3}} + \frac{a^{3}-b^{3}}{z^{4}} + \cdots \right) \\ \displaystyle = \left( \frac{1}{z^{2}} + \frac{a^{2}-b^{2}}{z^{3}(a-b)} + \frac{a^{3}-b^{3}}{z^{4}(a-b)} + \cdots \right)$

**Again, please let me know how to do part (a), as well as if my parts (b) and (c) are ok.** Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

For $\left|z\right|\lt\left|c\right|$,
$$
\frac1{z-c}=-\frac1c\left(1+\frac zc+\frac{z^2}{c^2}+\frac{z^3}{c^3}+\dots\right)
$$
For $\left|z\right|\gt\left|c\right|$,
$$
\frac1{z-c}=\frac1z\left(1+\frac cz+\frac{c^2}{z^2}+\frac{c^3}{z^3}+\dots\right)
$$
Apply these to
$$
\begin{align}
\frac1{(z-a)(z-b)}
&=\frac1{b-a}\left(\frac1{z-b}-\frac1{z-a}\right)\\
\end{align}
$$

Comment: this does not help me at all in the interval $0 < |z|<|a|$, though, which is the one I can't figure out at all how to do. Can you please tell me how to do that case at least?

Comment: Why not? In that region you can use $|z|\lt|c|$ for both $\frac1{z-a}$ and $\frac1{z-b}$.

Comment: and isn't what you have here exactly what I did in the cases for (b) and (c)? Did I make a mistake?

Comment: I assume by your work that you are trying to expand about $z=0$. That is why there are only powers of $z-0$ in the series. What else about $z=0$ do you think you need to include?

Comment: I think I'm trying to expand about $z=0$. Is there anything wrong with what I did? I think I understand how to do the first case now, but at least let me know if I did (b) and (c) right please.

Comment: Your work seems to be okay.

Comment: thanks man.  I'm giving (a) a shot right now based on your hints.

Answer (score 1):

For $|z|<|a|<|b|$, there are no singularities of $f(z)=\frac{1}{(z-a)(z-b)}$.  Thus, we write

$$\begin{align}
f(z)&=\frac{1}{a-b}\left(\frac{1}{z-a}-\frac{1}{z-b}\right)\\\\
&=\frac{1}{a-b}\left(\frac{1/b}{1-z/b}-\frac{1/a}{1-z/a}\right)\\\\
&=\frac{1}{a-b}\left(\frac{1}{b}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\frac{z}{b}\right)^n-\frac{1}{a}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\frac{z}{a}\right)^n\right)\\\\
&=\frac{1}{a-b}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{b^{n+1}}-\frac{1}{a^{n+1}}\right)z^n
\end{align}$$

Comment: ,, where am I working on this region?

Comment: Part (a), the one that was in question

Comment: What about the $0$ part??

Comment: If we interpret $0^0$ as $1$, this expansion works for $z=0$ also.  ;-))